# How to catch request and response data call in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Based on the diagram

[image]

I want to get the

1. Get request Data
2. Get Elapsed time between request and response call
3. Get response data

I was thinking if I could use `BeginRequest`, `EndRequest` under `System.Web.HttpApplication` inside `Global.asax`.

The very reason of this, is that, I want to know if the cause of slow operation is on the server, or just on the client mobile app.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the request and response with a DelegatingHandler - [Log message Request and Response in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/09/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx)

In the tutorial, you can find the complete explanation on how to read the Request/Response content using Buffers (or else if we read directly from stream ,then the content will not be available for later handlers/apicontrollers).